# ManyToOne Lazy loading not working Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have make the rest api using Spring boot. It has two entities employee and department. Employee has department object so relation is ManyToOne. It is unidirectional. Department do not have the employees list. When I hit the employees GET method endpoint I am getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException Exception. Please tell me how to solve it.

Employee Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Integer salary;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="department_id",referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false)
private Department department;
```

Department Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
public class Department {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String name;
```

Employee Service:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@Autowired
public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
    this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
}

public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
    return employeeRepository.findAll();
}

public Employee getEmployeeById(Integer id){
    Optional<Employee> optionalEmployee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
    if(optionalEmployee.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Department does not exists");
    }
    return optionalEmployee.get();
}

public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee){
    return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

Employee Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

private final EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired
public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}

@GetMapping
public List<Employee> getAllDepartments(){
    return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
}
   @PostMapping
public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    return employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
}}
```

Comment: You have to put `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` annotation in `ManyToOne`

Comment: Thankyou It is working.
But can I be able to access it to separate end point like
employee/id/department

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` annotation in `ManyToOne` relationship mapping

Comment: Can I be able to read it in separate endpoint or not.
And also can you tell me how can I achieve lazy loading

Comment: If you are beginner then bidirectional mapping is good instead unidirectional

Comment: Ok thankyou.
Can you share with a resource to learn about lazy loading.

Comment: @Professor See Here https://www.netsurfingzone.com/hibernate/many-to-one-unidirectional-mapping-in-hibernate-jpa-annotation-example-using-spring-boot-and-oracle/